# How to convert a CSV with data having comma inside quotes to JSON in Mule 4

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I am trying to convert a CSV with complex data to JSON but the quotes don't transform as expected.

Below is my flow in Mule application:

```
<flow name="csv-Flow">
    <file:listener doc:name="File" directory="${path}" config-ref="File-Inbound" outputMimeType="application/csv; quote='; escape=&quot;\\&quot;; separator=&quot;,&quot;; header=true">
        <scheduling-strategy>
            <fixed-frequency frequency="${frequency}"/>
        </scheduling-strategy>
    </file:listener>
    <set-payload value='#[%dw 2.0
    output application/json
    ---
    payload map {
     "Name": $."Name",
     "Address": $."Address",
     "Phone": $."Phone"
    }]' doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="#payload"/>
</flow>
```

**Input csv:**

```
Name,Address,Phone
xyz,"{""House No"":""SD/123"",""Street"":""First"",""State"":""PA""}",123456789
```

**Actual JSON Output:**

```
 {
  "Name": "xyz",
  "Address": "\"{\"\"House No\"\":\"\"SD/123\"\"",
  "Phone": "\"\"Street\"\":\"\"First\"\""
 }
```

**Expected JSON Output:**

```
{
 "Name": "xyz",
 "Address": "{"House No":"SD/123","Street":"First","State":"PA"}",
 "Phone": "123456789"
}
```

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the outputMimeType attribute of the File listener to:

```
outputMimeType='application/csv; quote="\""; header=true; escape="\"\""; separator=","'
```

The output will be:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "xyz",
    "Address": "{\"House No\":\"SD/123\",\"Street\":\"First\",\"State\":\"PA\"}",
    "Phone": "123456789"
  }
]
```

Note that the backslack '' characters are required by JSON to escape quotes inside a string. Your expected JSON output is not valid JSON because the quotes inside Address are not escaped correctly.

Also note that the payload is an array that the `map` function is iterating over, so the output is also an array in JSON.